# Detect null data in jQuery each loop

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I need to output some text when there is no data returned in a jQuery each loop but I am failing to do this after scouring this website, can someone please tell me where I am going wrong, if it helps the returned JSON data has an items array that has a value of 0, many thanks in advance!

Desired output - `console.log('No data has been returned');`

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://example.com/cart/change.json",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    id: remove_id,
    quantity: 0
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(index, item) {
      if (item === null) {
        console.log('empty cart');
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if elements in the array are `null`, or if the array itself is `null`?

Comment: Please show sample response when no items exist

Comment: I was trying to check if the array itself was null but found a much simpler way as there was a property set to null when the cart was empty. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there are no items, forEach will not loop. If item is undefined, `item === null` will return false.

To check if data.items returns a non empty array, do (outside of the loop)

```
if (data.items && data.items.length)
```

and to check if an item exists, simply do

```
if (!item)
```

Comment: i found there was a property in the JSON called item_count that was set to 0 if there were no items in the cart therefore I got it to work by using -  if (data.item_count == 0) just outside of the loop, your suggestions helped me out of a hole thank you!